# Flask and Celery large application structure

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am trying to use celery in an app to run long tasks asynchronously.

In the top project folder I have application.py:

```
from flask_stormpath import StormpathManager
from app import create_app
from celery import Celery

app = create_app('DevelopmentConfig')
stormpath_manager = StormpathManager(app)
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config.from_object('CELERY_BROKER_URL'))
celery.conf.update(app.config)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The config.py looks like this:

```
class Config:

    SECRET_KEY = 'something_very_secret'
    broker_url = 'sqs://'
    broker_transport_options = {'region': 'eu-west-1',
                                'visibility_timeout': 3600,
                                'polling_interval': 0.3,
                                'queue_name_prefix': 'celery-'}


    csrf = SECRET_KEY
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis: //localhost:6379/0'

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    JUST_SOMETHING = 'a_little_trick'
    DEBUG = True
    STORMPATH_API_KEY_FILE = '/.stormpath/apiKey.properties'
    STORMPATH_APPLICATION = 'flask-test'
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis: //localhost:6379/0'


class ProductionConfig(Config):
    JUST_SOMETHING = 'a_little_trick'
    DEBUG = True
    STORMPATH_API_KEY_FILE = '/.stormpath/apiKey.properties'
    STORMPATH_APPLICATION = 'flask-test'
    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqs://'

config = {'development': DevelopmentConfig,
          'default': DevelopmentConfig}
```

and in my views.py I try to run a task:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, request, jsonify, Response
from wtforms import Form, validators, SelectMultipleField, widgets
from flask_stormpath import login_required
from . import main
import numpy as np



class MultiCheckboxField(SelectMultipleField):
    widget = widgets.ListWidget(prefix_label=False)
    option_widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()


@celery.task(bin=True)
def do_something(test, training_size, testing_size):
```

Now, when I run it like this, I get the message that @celery.task the name celery was not defined. Fair point, so I changed it to @main.celery.task. When I do this, I get the error message "AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'celery'.

Then I tried to initiate celery in the **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
from celery import Celery

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    configuration = "config."+config_name
    app.config.from_object(configuration)

    celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config.from_object('CELERY_BROKER_URL'))
    celery.conf.update(app.config)


    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

When I do this, I get the error: ImportError: No module named CELERY_BROKER_URL

So, I don't know, where to import and initiate celery and how to create a blueprint so that I can use celery.task in views.py. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First of all you should move all celery tasks in one `module`. `celery = Celery(...)` should initialization in your module with tasks, but not in `def create_app`